# unable to restart lightdm

Tags: nvidia, lightdm

I have netbook with following hardware config:

1. Ubuntu 14.04
2. Intel i5 4th gen
3. NVIDIA 820m graphics card using Nouveau display driver v346

if I run `sudo service lightdm restart` I get black screen, instead of login screen, why is that?

NOTE:

1. I dont get such problem if I am using Intel display driver instead of NVIDIA display driver
2. I tried using different versions of NVIDIA drivers but got same problem on all

Update: link to my `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10705662/)

Comment: most likely a driver issue: what does `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` tell you?

Comment: @umläute link to my `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10705662/)